# "So as to make difficult the test" or "So as to make the test difficult"

Tags: adjectives, transitivity, direct-objects

Can one use (a) instead of (b)?

> a. We changed the questions so as to make difficult the test.
>
> b. We changed the questions so as to make the test difficult.

Or can one use (c) instead of (d)?

> c. We changed the questions so as to make more difficult the test.
>
> d. We changed the questions so as to make the test more difficult.

Comment: (b) and (d) are acceptable, (a) and (c) are not.

Answer (score 1):

B and D are natural English, although A and C are not. However, there are some exceptions that allow us to make sentences just as in your A and C examples. For example, if you have a relative clause modifying the noun "*test*" and it is long enough to keep "*make*" and "*difficult*" really far away from each other, then you can use A and C versions of it.

An example;

> We changed the questions so as to make the test that is going to include fluid mechanics and thermodynamics questions at the same time difficult.

This sentence doesn't really read well and easily. However, you had better say:

> We changed the questions so as to make difficult the test that is going to include fluid mechanics and thermodynamics questions at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

> a. We changed the questions so as to make difficult the test.
> b. We changed the questions so as to make the test difficult.
> c. We changed the questions so as to make more difficult the test. 
> d. We changed the questions so as to make the test more difficult.

(a) and (c) are ungrammatical because in English a direct object must directly follow its verb.

However, sometimes you can break this rule.

There's a construction called [Heavy NP Shift](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_NP_shift), in which a noun phrase that is heavy (long and complex) may be moved to the end of the sentence and other elements are allowed to intervene between a verb and a direct object. Here's an example of Heavy NP Shift:

> I met on the street my rich uncle from Detroit
>
> (Wikipedia)

In this case, the direct object "my rich uncle from Detroit" is longer and more complex than "on my street", so the direct object is moved to the final position and "on my street" is placed between the verb and the complex noun phrase.